# How to store indicies of an array in preprocessor defines?

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I am creating a VST(virtual instrument) program in cpp and I have an array of structs that represent various parameters in my program:

```
const FloatParam_Properties FloatParamProps[NUM_FLOAT_PARAMS] =
{
    //Frequency
    {"BaseFreq",    "Base Freq",    0.0,    20.0,   5.0,    0.6},   //0 
    {"FreqDelta",   "Freq Delta",   -20.0,  20.0,   0.0,    0.6},   //1
    ...

    //Wave
    {"OscSelect",   "Wave form",    0.0,    3.0,    0.0,    1.0},   //9

    //Master
    {"Volume",      "Volume",       0.0,    1.0,    0.1,    0.4},   //10
};
```

Each element in this array is a struct, when I want to access these structs I have just hardcoded the indices(e.g. doing `FloatParamProps[0]` to access the Base Frequency). However, I would like to use the cpp preprocessor to give these hard-coded indices a name since everything here is known at compile-time and it would be good if I didn't have to just hard-code those defines either.

What I would like to do is something like:

```
const FloatParam_Properties FloatParamProps[NUM_FLOAT_PARAMS] =
{
    //Frequency
    DEF_FLOAT_PARAM(BaseFreq,    "Base Freq",    0.0,    20.0,   5.0,    0.6),   //0 
    DEF_FLOAT_PARAM(FreqDelta,   "Freq Delta",   -20.0,  20.0,   0.0,    0.6),   //1
    ...

    //Wave
    DEF_FLOAT_PARAM(OscSelect,   "Wave form",    0.0,    3.0,    0.0,    1.0),   //9

    //Master
    DEF_FLOAT_PARAM(Volume,      "Volume",       0.0,    1.0,    0.1,    0.4),   //10
};
```

Where `DEF_FLOAT_PARAM` was a macro that would then take the first argument and turn that into a pre-processor define(or maybe constexpr) by using the `__COUNTER__` macro. Then, if I wanted to access the first one I could do `FloatParamProps[BaseFreq]`, for example. The issue I'm having is that you can't have a define within a macro so I can't define BaseFreq as a constant.

I also tried doing something like

```
#define DEF_FLOAT_PARAM(ID, Name, minVal, maxVal, defaultVal, skewFactor) P_##ID __COUNTER__ \
            {#ID, Name, minVal, maxVal, defaultVal, skewFactor},
```

and the plan here was to try and take the define outside of the macro and just type that manually like so:

```
const FloatParam_Properties FloatParamProps[NUM_FLOAT_PARAMS] =
{
    //Frequency
    #define DEF_FLOAT_PARAM(BaseFreq,    "Base Freq",    0.0,    20.0,   5.0,    0.6),   //0
    ...
```

But the issue with that is that the pre-processor doesn't want to expand that macro when it's in-front of the define. If only I could tell it to expand the macro, it would work.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't `#define` a macro within a macro, but you *can* define an `enum`, which does pretty much everything a macro does other than support `ifdef`

Comment: @o11c Except that you can't define an `enum` inside the middle of an array.  So trying to make `DEF_FLOAT_PARAM()` define both the struct element and the index of it at the same time simply won't work. You'd need separate macros for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [x-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro):

```
#define PARAMS(X) \
    X(BaseFreq,    "Base Freq",    0.0,    20.0,   5.0,    0.6) \
    X(FreqDelta,   "Freq Delta",   -20.0,  20.0,   0.0,    0.6) \
    X(OscSelect,   "Wave form",    0.0,    3.0,    0.0,    1.0)

const FloatParam_Properties FloatParamProps[NUM_FLOAT_PARAMS] =
{
    #define PARAM_STRUCT(id, ...) {#id, __VA_ARGS__},
    PARAMS(PARAM_STRUCT)
    #undef PARAM_STRUCT
};

enum Params
{
    #define PARAM_ENUM(id, ...) id,
    PARAMS(PARAM_ENUM)
    #define PARAM_ENUM
    _count,
};
```

This will generate the same array you already have, and a enum with the constants matching the array indices.

Comment: Note that using the `#include "params.def"` style of x-macros may be more readable.

Comment: @KamilCuk The string names seem to be slightly different from IDs.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Yes but his UDT apparently has fields for both, see the first code block in the question.

Comment: Cool, try this: `PARAMS("French Fries")`.  Another reason not to use macros.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I for one like [DRY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself) more than I dislike macros. Templates can produce unreadable errors too if you misuse them.